# How to disable Oracle's recycle bin?

Tags: oracle

At work, our DBAs have disabled the recycle bin. At home, while answering stackoverflow questions, I create a lot of tables, which are dropped very quicky.

I would like to disable the recyblebin. While researching, I found two methods:

```
ALTER SESSION SET RECYCLEBIN = OFF;
```

and even

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET RECYCLEBIN = OFF DEFERRED;
```

However, I'm using Oracle's vagrant boxes, so how can I disable the recyclebin while installing the database, or in other words with init parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any other initialization parameter, you can set the initial value of the `recyclebin` parameter in the text initialization file **initSID.ora**:

```
recyclebin=off
```

and also as suggested by @Kumar, you can set it afterward as:

`alter system set recyclebin = OFF SCOPE = SPFILE SID='*'`

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/tables011.htm):

> Disabling the recycle bin does not purge or otherwise affect objects
>   already in the recycle bin. The recycle bin is enabled by default.
>
> You enable and disable the recycle bin by changing the recyclebin
>   initialization parameter. This parameter is not dynamic, so a database
>   restart is required when you change it with an ALTER SYSTEM statement.

To check the parameter value:

```
SQL> show parameter recyclebin;

NAME         TYPE        VALUE
------------ ----------- ----------
recyclebin   string      ON
```

**To disable the recycle bin:**

Session level:

```
ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = OFF;
```

Database level:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET recyclebin = OFF SCOPE = SPFILE; -- Requires database restart
```

To remove all dropped objects from the recyclebin (current user):

```
PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
```

To remove all dropped objects from the recyclebin (system wide, available to `SYSDBA` only or, starting with version `12c`, to users having the `PURGE DBA_RECYCLEBIN` system privilege):

```
PURGE DBA_RECYCLEBIN;
```